# Hive plots in vega-lite (and Altair?)

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I was wondering if there's something similar to Hive plots in vega-lite and/or Altair (python):

[image]

http://hiveplot.com/

Or if somebody approached that problem in the past w/ vega-lite (I know there's something available for JS and Matplotlib). It'd make my data analysis that much clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had attempted to add `altair` support to [hiveplotlib](https://geomdata.gitlab.io/hiveplotlib/), which I maintain, but I ran into an issue with drawing arbitrary curves in 2d, discussed more [here](https://gitlab.com/geomdata/hiveplotlib/-/issues/7#note_1061705994).

I couldn't find a solution to this problem, so I abandoned `altair` support for now. I'm not an `altair` user though, so if you or someone else can solve that bit, I can support hive plots in `altair`.